# What rendering framework does blender use?

Tags: rendering, scripting

Does it use OpenGL?  Crystalspace?  Ogre?  I want to change the rendering system but I don't know what framework blender uses.  Also, what physics engine does blender use?

Comment: OpenGL - https://www.blender.org/bf/codelayout.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Blender, by default, uses its own rendering systems, depending on selection.

- The offline renderer is a path tracing engine called Cycles.
- The online renderer is a rasterization based engine called Eevee.
- Both rendering engines harness CPU and GPU to different degrees, including the OpenGL, OpenCL, and CUDA based GPU libraries.

Blender used portions of Bullet for some physics calculations, with other approaches for its particle system interactions.

Answer (score 0):

According to their website, blender 2.76 and older is using OpenGL 1.4, and starting from 2.77 is using OpenGL 2.1